# Best way to translate routes

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate for translation but in my project I need to translate routes too.
For example

EN -> site.com/about-company
PT -> site.com/pt/sobre-companhia

Are the any plugin or solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-routes.

Here is the active demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-routes-example.

The package will translate the current English route to the target language.

If you want it the other way around, i.e. when someone goes to site.com/pt/sobre-companhia, to open the AboutCompany component, you just need to set up two routes for the same component in route config, something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutCompany, data: {lang: 'en'} },
  { path: 'sobre-companhia', component: AboutCompany, data: {lang: 'pt'} },
]
```

Comment: Our path names are dynamic.. Also this plugin looks like gets download 1 a day. So I thought that it is not mature.